Как организовать вывод имени страницы, связанной с полем Relationship Field в payload
Доброго времени суток я Использую безголовую CMS payload и у меня встала дилемма.

Мне нужно, чтобы в поле Link отображалось значение из связанной коллекции Pages (значение из поля name: 'NamePage'). В данный момент выводится только ID страницы, что неудобно, так как непонятно, какая именно страница связана.
import Heading from '../blocks/Heading'
import { CollectionConfig } from 'payload/types'
export const Pages: CollectionConfig  = {
    slug: 'pages',
    labels: {
        singular: 'Страница',
        plural: 'Страницы',
    },
    access:{
        read: () => true,
      },
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'NamePage',
            label: 'Название страницы',
            type: 'text',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'URL',
            label: 'Адресс страницы',
            type: 'text',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'layout',
            label: 'Шаблон',
            type: 'blocks',
            blocks: [
                Heading,
            ]
        }
    ]
}

код поля Link
import type { Field } from 'payload/types'
import type { UploadField } from 'payload/dist/fields/config/types'

export const LinkField = (options?: Partial<UploadField>): Field => ({
    ...options,
    name: 'Link',
    type: 'relationship', 
    relationTo: 'pages', 
    hasMany: false,
    admin: {
        width: '50%', 
      }
});


просто нужно добавить
admin: {
    useAsTitle: 'namepage',
},   

получается вот так
 import Heading from '../blocks/Heading'
    import { CollectionConfig } from 'payload/types'
    export const Pages: CollectionConfig  = {
        slug: 'pages',
       admin: {
            useAsTitle: 'namepage',
        },
        labels: {
            singular: 'Страница',
            plural: 'Страницы',
        },
        access:{
            read: () => true,
          },
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'NamePage',
                label: 'Название страницы',
                type: 'text',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'URL',
                label: 'Адресс страницы',
                type: 'text',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'layout',
                label: 'Шаблон',
                type: 'blocks',
                blocks: [
                    Heading,
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

